# How to handle quantity if it changed via Firebug?

Tags: python, django, firebug, payment-gateway

Please, help me with advice or soo.

I'm working on integration of 2Checkout gateway on my website and i face interesting situation. I have a button named "Buy from 2CO", which is a part of buying form.

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.2checkout.com/checkout/purchase">
    <p>
        <input type="hidden" value="1952334" name="sid">
        <input type="hidden" value="1" name="quantity">
        <input type="hidden" value="Y" name="fixed">
        <input type="hidden" value="4" name="product_id">
        <input type="submit" value="Buy from 2CO" name="submit">
    </p>
</form>
```

Form has quantity input which is hidden but can be changed with Firebug. And form can be submited. After that you will be pointed to payment page, like this:

http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/918/cce262e54eb645bb98aa7e3.png

Here you can see that "Quantity" is "1".
If I set quantity in my buying form, for example, to "5" it will be submited too and i will have this picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2Nkj.png

User can procced to the next section and make payment.

In total: user can pay twiced price for my subscription, can manually set quantity and then request charge back and make many problems to me and payment gateway.

How to handle that behavior?

Comment: They can post arbitrary requests to 2checkout without a form at all, there's nothing you can do. If they wish to pay for 5 months upfront, let them.

Comment: @PavelAnossov, that's true. But if that payment will recure every month? I mean my client will be charged with $75, as he paid first time. Really don't know how 2checkout will handle those payments of monthly recuring items.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is **you can't**. *Any* client-side code can be manipulated and submitted using Firebug or just plain JavaScript.

You would need to either hold, or validate your values server-side before they are submitted to the service in order to make sure they are correct.

Comment: That's the problem. If someone change quantity of subscriptions(stupid) from 1 to 5 and pay for them, his money will be charged via payment gateway and i will only receive messege that "someone bought 5 monthly subscriptions" O_o

Comment: Sorry, that's simply the way it is. My suggestion would be to refactor your code to hold the values for your cart server-side. I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: If someone pay twice for monthly subscription by submiting POST request to payment gateway what i should do with that payment? Simple accept it and count that user pay for 2 month? This will cause problem with subscription recuring via gateway.

Comment: Your code, as it currently stands, will NOT prevent the behavior you're trying to prevent. You need to refactor your code

Comment: User can submit hand-maded URL with quantity=5 and pay for them. Please, read question carefully.
https://www.2checkout.com/checkout/purchase?sid=1952334&quantity=5&product_id=4

Comment: Then pick a different vendor!

Comment: Why not use Stripe.com? Then you won't have anything to worry about, as you can hold all of your values server-side.'

Comment: Gonna take a look at Stripe.com.